# css свойства только на родительский элемент

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть меню ul:

```
<ul class="first-lvl">
    <li>1
        <ul class="second-lvl">
            <li>1 > 1</li>
            <li>1 > 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

c двумя уровнями , так вот я применяю стили такими селекторами:

```
first-lvl.ul {}

first-lvl.ul li {}

first-lvl.ul li  a {}
```

Проблема что стили с первого уровня попадают на второй уровень , и приходится в новом селекторе обнулять прописаные стили: margin,padding и т.д

Можно ли как то добиться того чтобы не распространялись стили на второй уровень меню?

Comment: Используйте дочерние секторы (`ul.first-lvl > li`): http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/dochernie-selektory

Comment: @w3lifer , пробовал, так не работает

Comment: Тогда дайте полный код.

Answer (score 1):

Все работает прекрасно, поймите, тут идет скорее не наследование, а как пример в моем коде бекграунд `li` верхнего уровня покрывает бекграунд `li` нижнего уровня, если его не перекрыть другими стилями.

```css
ul.first-lvl > li {
  background-color: tomato;
}
ul > li> ul > li {
  background-color: green;
}
/* или */

/*
ul.first-lvl > li> ul.second-lvl > li {
 background-color: yellow;
}
*/
```

```html
<ul class="first-lvl">
  <li>1
    <ul class="second-lvl">
      <li>1 > 1</li>
      <li>1 > 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```